# How to play 240fps AVCapture Session movie by MPMoviePlayerController?

Tags: ios, mpmovieplayercontroller, avcapturesession

I was able to record 240[fps] AVCapture Session movie to my Album.
But I cannot play the movie with slow motion.
How can I get?

I have tried following situation.

[1] 
I tried following code.
AVCapture session delegate is handled 240[fps] "outputFileURL".
But in the result, MPMoviePlayerController plays normal fps movie.

```
- (void)                 captureOutput:(AVCaptureFileOutput *)captureOutput
   didFinishRecordingToOutputFileAtURL:(NSURL *)outputFileURL
                       fromConnections:(NSArray *)connections error:(NSError *)error
{


   MPMoviePlayerController *player = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:assetURL];

   player.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleNone;
   player.scalingMode = MPMovieScalingModeNone;
   player.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeFile;


   player.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
   [self.view addSubview:player.view];
   [player prepareToPlay];
   [player play];

}
```

[2]
I tried following code. This code simply play movie which is recored by iOS Default Camera App. This code can play slow motion. But I want to know the way to record & play slow motion movie in all by my code.

```
NSString* path=[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"test.mov" ofType:@""];
NSURL* url=[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
MPMoviePlayerController *player = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:assetURL];

player.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleNone;
player.scalingMode = MPMovieScalingModeNone;
player.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeFile;

player.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
[self.view addSubview:player.view];
[player prepareToPlay];
[player play];
```

Do you have any ideas ??